# Neat ggplot-esque way to plot a time series that is rebased at each year start

Tags: r, ggplot2

I manage to get the plot I need (see below), but not in a clean way (see code and the several `geom_line` calls). I would want to be able to get the same plot that dynamically adjusts to the number of years I have.

```
data %>%
  ggplot +
  geom_line(aes(x = request_dt, y = `2015`, color = decile)) +
  geom_line(aes(x = request_dt, y = `2016`, color = decile)) +
  geom_line(aes(x = request_dt, y = `2017`, color = decile)) +
  geom_line(aes(x = request_dt, y = `2018`, color = decile)) +
  geom_line(aes(x = request_dt, y = `2019`, color = decile)) +
  geom_line(aes(x = request_dt, y = `2020`, color = decile)) +
  geom_line(aes(x = request_dt, y = `2021`, color = decile))
```

My dataframe looks like this:

[image]

```
set.seed(1234)

dates <- rep(seq(ymd("2015-01-01"), ymd("2020-01-01"), by = "1 day"), 10)
deciles <- as.factor(rep(seq(1, 10, 1), length(dates)/10))
deciles <- deciles[order(deciles)]
returns <- c(rnorm(length(dates)/10, mean = 0, sd = 10e-4),
             rnorm(length(dates)/10, mean = 0, sd = 10e-4),
             rnorm(length(dates)/10, mean = 0, sd = 10e-4),
             rnorm(length(dates)/10, mean = 0, sd = 10e-4),
             rnorm(length(dates)/10, mean = 0, sd = 10e-4),
             rnorm(length(dates)/10, mean = 0, sd = 10e-4),
             rnorm(length(dates)/10, mean = 0, sd = 10e-4),
             rnorm(length(dates)/10, mean = 0, sd = 10e-4),
             rnorm(length(dates)/10, mean = 0, sd = 10e-4),
             rnorm(length(dates)/10, mean = 0, sd = 10e-4))

data <- data.frame(date = dates,
                   decile = deciles,
                   ret = returns) %>%
    mutate(year = lubridate::year(date)) %>%
    group_by(decile, year) %>%
        mutate(nav = 100*cumprod(1 + ret))

data %>%
    ggplot +
    geom_line(aes(x = date, y = nav, color = decile))
```

Thanks.

PS: I cannot use `dplyr::pivot_longer` because doing so draws one line per decile, and therefore links the point at the end of year `N` to the point at the beginning of year `N+1`, which is not ideal for clarity.

[image]

Comment: You'll have to use `pivot_longer` in some way to achieve that. How about providing a minimal reproducible dataset? :)

Comment: Just added a minimal reproductible example :)

Comment: Does adding `group = interaction(decile, year)` to the `aes()` of your `geom_line()`  not work?

Comment: Thanks @teunbrand! I had never used `interaction` before. It is clean now!